# Pair Sum Algorithm - Why is min and max needed

Tags: python, algorithm, max, min

I am working through the algorithm below.  I understand everything up until:

```
ourList.add((min(a1,a2),max(a1,a2)))
```

Why are min and max needed?  I'm sure it is something simple but if someone could help explain this in simple terms that would be greatly appreciated.

```
'''Given an input array, and a target key, 
   write a function that returns all unique pairs
   that sum up to the target key '''

def pairSum(numArr, key):
    ourList = set()
    for a1 in numArr:
        a2 = key - a1
        if a2 in numArr:
            ourList.add((min(a1,a2),max(a1,a2)))
    return ourList
```

Comment: Because `ourList` is a `set` and you do not want duplicate pairs. If you were to add `(1, 2)` and `(2, 1)` to the set you would have duplicates. Having the smaller value first every time ensures you do not have this duplication

Comment: perfect explanation!  That makes sense.  I appreciate that.

Comment: It would make more sense not to call it `ourList` when it is a set rather than a list. Also, since you're doing many `in numArr` tests, it would make sense to use a set for that, too.

Comment: @kaya3 is there a hard rule about when to use a set vs list?

Comment: Sets are undordered collections of distinct elements, so use a list if you need it to be ordered and/or contain duplicates. Membership tests (i.e. `in` or `not in`) in a list require searching in O(n) time, whereas membership tests on a set are O(1) time, so if you need to do a lot of membership tests, use a set.